# PHP MYSQL ranking gives first rank as a zero

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ranking

I am presently working on a PHP application that ranks a set of result from MySQL and then displays them on a web page. I make three MySQLi queries and then display the result in a rank. Everything seems fine but at certain times (without a regular pattern), the result displayed sometimes shows 0 as the first rank instead of 1, some shows 1 though.

I have tried debugging the code for the past month but there are no headways, I have had to rewrite the code that performs the query completely on different occasions but the zero 0 problem still persists.

Below is my code:

*This is the first section:*

```
$sql0       = "SET @rank = 0, @prev_val3 = NULL;";
$pull_report_details5 = "SELECT rank, score, student_number, subject_name, gender FROM (
                    SELECT @rank := IF(@prev_val3=score,@rank,@rank+1) AS rank, @prev_val3 := score AS score, student_number, subject_name, gender
                    FROM uploaded_results WHERE `subject_name` = '$subject_name' ORDER BY score DESC
                    ) as result";
mysqli_query($dbc, $sql0)or mysql_error();
$push_pull_report_details5 = mysqli_query($dbc, $pull_report_details5)or die("Error pulling report details");
```

*The second section:*

```
$sql1       = "SET @rank2 = 0, @prev_val2 = NULL;";
$pull_report_details3 = "SELECT rank2, score, student_number, subject_name, gender FROM (
                    SELECT @rank2 := IF(@prev_val2=score,@rank2,@rank2+1) AS rank2, @prev_val2 := score AS score, student_number, subject_name, gender
                    FROM uploaded_results WHERE `subject_name` = '$subject_name' AND `gender` = 'Male' ORDER BY score DESC
                    ) as result";
mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1)or mysql_error();
$push_pull_report_details3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $pull_report_details3)or die(mysqli_error($dbc)."failure");
```

*The third section:*

```
$sql2       = "SET @rank1 = 0, @prev_val = NULL;";
$pull_report_details4 = "SELECT rank1, score, student_number, subject_name, gender FROM (
                    SELECT @rank1 := IF(@prev_val=score,@rank1,@rank1+1) AS rank1, @prev_val := score AS score, student_number, subject_name, gender
                    FROM uploaded_results WHERE `subject_name` = '$subject_name' AND `gender` = 'Female' ORDER BY score DESC
                    ) as result2";
mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2)or mysql_error();
$push_pull_report_details4 = mysqli_query($dbc, $pull_report_details4)or die("Error pulling report details");
```

Lastly, I display the three queries on three different tables.

Comment: Guessing: Per the [documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), **the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.** Your code assumes that the @ rank is based on the value of @ prev_val from the previous row.

Comment: Can you create a small dataset which can reproduce your problem?

Comment: This `mysql_error()` for one thing, does not mix with the MySQLi_ API. It needs to read as `mysqli_error($dbc)` should there be any errors in your code.

Comment: Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for the PHP/variables, should those be failing also.

Comment: @Agrizzo, if i get what you mean correctly, i anticipated the same thing. Thats why i used distinct variables throughput the queries, you will notice that there is rank, rank1 and rank2. There is also prev_val, prev_val2 and pev_val3

Comment: @Fred -ii- it displays the table perfectly without any error, just that the ranking is wrong. Its hard to catch any errors this way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried reporting all errors